# Deleting records less than max sequence number in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a table with the following columns

Below are some of the records

```
DOC_ID  DOC_NAME  ORG_ID ADD_DT
1                123.DOC              1            4/1/2014
2                124.DOC              1            4/2/2014
3                125.DOC              1            4/1/2014
4                126.DOC              1            4/1/2014
5                123.DOC              2            4/1/2014
6                124.DOC              2            4/2/2014
7                125.DOC              2            4/1/2014
8                126.DOC              2            4/1/2014
```

How do I keep the records with max DOC_ID for each ORG_ID and delete all the others.

What I want to see in my table is

```
DOC_ID  DOC_NAME  ORG_ID ADD_DT
4                126.DOC              1            4/1/2014
8                126.DOC              2            4/1/2014
```

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `rank()` analytic function to find the rows you'd want to remove, and correlate between them by using the `rowid` pseudocolum.

```
DELETE FROM my_table
WHERE ROWID IN (SELECT ROWID 
                FROM   (SELECT RANK() OVER 
                        (PARTITION BY org_id ORDER BY doc_id DESC) AS rk
                        FROM   my_table)
                 WHERE rk > 1)
```